# Calculate average from 3 tables with R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data that consists of 3 files: file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv.
The files are replicate measurements.
Each file consists of 96 values, arranged in 12 columns (1-12) and 8 rows (a-h). 
I need to calculate the mean of each measurement in the 3 replicates (e.g. the mean of a1(file1, file2, file3), a2, etc). 
I don't need the mean by column or by row - I need the mean of the triplicate measurements for each cell (sorry, can't help thinking in Excel terms).

So I read each file into R, then add a "key" column with values = rep1 for file1, rep2 for file 2 and rep3 for file 3 as such:

```
file1 <- file1 %>% add_column(rep = rep1)
file2 <- file2 %>% add_column(rep = rep2)
file3 <- file3 %>% add_column(rep = rep3)
```

I then use dplyr's bind_rows() to generate one df containing all data,

```
all.data <- bind_rows(file1, file2, file3)
```

and finally use

`finally <- aggregate(all.data, list(all.data$rep), mean)`

My R skills are rudimentary and I am sure there MUST be a more elegant, strainghtforward way of doing this. Would love to know how!

Answer (score 2):

In `dplyr`, we can use `.id` parameter to add unique index for each dataframe instead of using `add_column` on each dataframe individually. We can then `group_by` this unique index and use `summarise_all` to get `mean` of all the columns by group.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(file1, file2, file3, .id = "rep") %>%
   group_by(rep) %>%
   summarise_all(mean)
```

---

Similar way using `data.table` would be to use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(file1, file2, file3),idcol = 'rep')[, lapply(.SD, mean), rep]
```